# Using stored procedures for non database related tasks

Tags: stored-procedures, logic, clr

Is it possible for a program to store all or some of its functions as stored procedures in a database and call them as needed. In other words placing some of program logic in database stored procedures.

Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms345099(v=sql.100)) about it in Microsoft docs.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're asking here.  T-SQL is technically Turing complete, so in theory anything is possible.  But just because you *can* do a thing doesn't mean you *should* do that thing.

Comment: On a related note, the last place I worked for actually stored C# code in the database, retrieved it as needed, compiled it on the fly using CSScript and executed it in a process.  It was essentially an implementation of the Actor model.

Comment: To elaborate more: I am reviewing an enterprise software for my company. I asked for more flexibility than it already provide and been told that I can store any C# code in the database. This way I could add any functionality that I needed.  I need to know if it is really practical.

Comment: Yes, it is really practical.  We did it successfully at my last job.

Comment: If you have any questions beyond "is it possible or practical," please ask.

Comment: Is it easy to pass parameters and get the a returned value?

Comment: The environment in which the C# code runs is inside SQL server? Or caller?

Comment: It has a JSON endpoint.  The returned value is essentially side-effects, the result of operations on the database.  It doesn't run inside SQL server, nor does it run on the caller.  It will run on any machine that is registered with the SQL Server (in a registration table).

Comment: See [here](https://workflowengine.io/server/) for something similar.